# fixed header and margins

Tags: css

My problem is having a fixed navigation at the top of the page and setting the rest of the document to margin: 0 auto; so that when the page is expanded, everything stays in the center. Is there a way to have the fixed header stay fixed at the center of the page when the page expands and contracts as well as it moving up and down as the page scrolls or no?

```
.container {
     max-width: 1200px;
     height: 1200px;
     position: relative;
     border: 0px;
     text-align: center;
     left: 30px;
 }
 .header {
     width: 1200px;
     height: 140px;
     padding: 0px;
     border: 0px;
     background-color: white;
     position: fixed;
     left: 50%;
     top: 0px;
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nav has a fixed width? Your HTML/CSS code would be wishfull.

But having to guess, I think this might help:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px; /* 50% of the elements width */
}
.content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/5DBXt/).